# How to handle the result of a completion block between classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, objective-c-blocks, completion

Let's say I have a class `UploadManager` and I create an instance of it in my `ViewController`. `UploadManager.m` has a method `-(void)requestData`

```
-(void)requestData
{
    HTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] init];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(HTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        // Do something here
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

Now I can call the `requestData` method from my instance of `UploadManager` in `ViewController.m`, but I'd like to do something with the `responseObject` inside of `ViewController.m` once the completion block has fired. What's the best way of doing this? I assume I could make a delegate method but I'm wondering if there's a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: Delegates or notification can be used.

Comment: It's a block. You can add any code that you like in the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use blocks structure for that

```
   -(void)requestDataWithHandler:(void (^)(id responceObject))handler
    {
        HTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] init];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(HTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
            // Do something here

        if(handler)
        {
           handler(responceObject)
        }
        }];
        [operation start];
    }
```

In another class

```
 [uploadManager requestDataWithHandler:^(responceObject) {
    // here work with responeObject
    }];
```

Comment: You should check `if (handler)` before calling, so you won't crash if it's `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

The block-based approach will certainly work. If you want an alternate approach to blocks, you could use `NSNotifications` as follows:

```
-(void)requestDataWithHandler:(void (^)(id responseObject))handler
{
    HTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] init];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(HTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        // You'll probably want to define the Notification name elsewhere instead of saying @"Information updated" below.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Information updated" object:nil];
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

Elsewhere in `ViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSomethingUponUpdate) name:@"Information updated" object:nil];
}

-(void)dealloc
{ 
  // Don't forget to remove the observer, or things will get unpleasant
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)doSomethingUponUpdate
{
  // Something
}
```